# how to increase or decrease the quantity in a field in my sql when we enter the new quantity

Tags: mysql, jsp

I'm doing a project I'm encountering a problem in my project.........

the problem is  i would like to increase or decrease the quantity in my sql quantity field when i pass the issued or delivered quantity i.e....
initially the quantity in the quantity filed is 1 when i intake the product of a quantity 10 then automatically it should update the quantity as 10+1=11
so it must update as 11, if i remove a 1 quantity it should update as 0........

how to write a code in jsp..........

pls do help

Answer (score 2):

if you want to `INCREMENT` the value of product, use the query below

```
UPDATE tableName SET columnName = columnName + toadd
```

and `DECREMENT`

```
UPDATE tableName SET columnName = columnName - tosubtract
```

so to apply in your case,

```
UPDATE tableName SET quantity = quantity + 10

or

UPDATE tableName SET quantity = quantity - 1
```

Comment: my Query is  <UPDATE im_stock_table SET im_quantiy_available='im_quantiy_available-4' WHERE im_barcode='8902261131009' > .after execution im_quantiy_available goes 0 ,please help me

Comment: Worked by changing <UPDATE im_stock_table SET im_quantiy_available=im_quantiy_available-'4' WHERE im_barcode='8902261131009' > :)